# Own cls to fmt conversion

Tags: format-files

Is it possible to convert my own `.cls` to `.fmt` conversion using PdfTeX?

**NOTE:** Our peoples are frequently change/updations in class file (source `.cls` file). So that I would like to convert non-editable class format.

Comment: look at the `mylatexformat` package which helps in compiling  a custom format based on a document preamble loading specific classes and packages.

Comment: Did this help? The question is still unanswered.

Comment: Are there any news here? <- for later google search

Comment: Still i have not found the solution. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does the class have options?

Comment: If the class is frequently changed, then the class should be improved by adding features and easier configurations, fixing bugs, improving documentation, ...

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: No this file is not having any options and public latex class file `elsarticle` or `revtex4` only. Could you please advise how to do convert `cls` to `fmt` format?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Procedure for a format, which has a class preloaded. The class is named `theclass` in the following.

### The class file

Because the class is already loaded in the format, global/class options cannot be specified any longer. Configuration can be implemented by a `\theclasssetup` command as done by many packages and some classes, e.g. `\sisetup` of package `siunitx` or `\hypersetup` for some of the options of package `hyperref`.

A dummy class file `theclass.cls` for testing:

```
% File: theclass.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{theclass}[2015/07/02 v1.0 Class for something]

% Implementation of the class
\LoadClass{article}

\endinput
```

### `theclass.ini` file for the format generation

The new format file consists of LaTeX and the class. The file `theclass.ini` contain the commands for the format. LaTeX is not loaded, because the available LaTeX formats can be reused. But the class needs to be loaded and `\documentclass` redefined to allow normal LaTeX documents that can be processed with the format with or without the class preloaded.

```
% File: theclass.ini
%
% Check for e-TeX
\expandafter\ifx\csname eTeXversion\endcsname\relax
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\{=1
    \catcode`\}=2
    \catcode`\^=7
    \newlinechar=10 %
    \def\space{ }
    \def\MessageBreak{^^J\space\space}
    \errmessage{%
      The eTeX extension is missing.\MessageBreak
      It can be enabled by option `-etex`\MessageBreak
      or starting the first filename with a star `*'.\MessageBreak
      The format generation is aborted%
    }
  \endgroup
  \csname fi\endcsname % end \ifx
  \csname @@end\endcsname % for the case a LaTeX format is already loaded
  \end % end job
\fi

% Load class
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass{theclass}\relax

% Now we have to redefine \documentclass to get valid user documents.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\documentclass}[2][]{%
  \def\reserved@a{#2}%
  \ifx\reserved@a\theclass@name
    \def\reserved@a{#1}%
    \ifx\reserved@a\@empty
    \else
      \ClassWarningNoLine{theclass}{%
        This format has already loaded the class\MessageBreak
        and does not support global options.\MessageBreak
        The following options are ignored:\MessageBreak
        \@spaces[#1]%
      }%
    \fi 
      \expandafter\theclass@datecheck
  \else
    \ClassError{theclass}{%
      This format has already loaded the class `theclass'\MessageBreak
      and cannot be used with other classes.\MessageBreak
      LaTeX run is aborted%
    }\@ehd
    \expandafter\@@end % abort job.
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\theclass@name}{theclass}
\newcommand*{\theclass@datecheck}[1][]{%
  \@ifclasslater{theclass}{#1}{%
  }{%
    \@latex@warning@no@line{%
      You have requested,\on@line,
      version\MessageBreak
      `#1' of class\space\theclass@name,\MessageBreak
      but only version\MessageBreak
      `\csname ver@\theclass@name.cls\endcsname'\MessageBreak
      is available in this format%
    }%
  }%  
}     

% Format identification
\begingroup
  \edef\x{%
    \noexpand\typeout{%
      Class \theclass@name\space \@nameuse{ver@\theclass@name.cls}.%
    }%
    \noexpand\typeout{%
      Format created at \the\year/\two@digits\month/\two@digits\day
      \space by class author.%
    }%
  }%  
\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\everyjob\expandafter{\the\expandafter\everyjob\x}
\makeatother

% Generate format
\dump
\endinput
```

### Format generation

This is shown for TeX Live (2015) for `pdflatex`. Since the format for `pdflatex` is already available, it is reused by `&pdflatex`. The special character `&` usually needs to be escaped on a command line, e.g. `\&pdflatex` (bash) or `"&pdflatex"`. Option `--ini` enables iniTeX mode. In this case option `--etex` is not given, because it is inherited from the imported format file of `pdflatex`.

```bash
pdflatex --ini "&pdflatex" theclass.ini
```

This generates the format file `theclass.fmt`.
(In the past the extension was `.efmt` with eTeX extensions.)

### Usage

Test file:

```
\documentclass{theclass}
% or \documentclass{theclass}[2015/07/02]
\begin{document}
Hello Word!
\end{document}
```

The new format `theclass.fmt` can be loaded with `&` (should be supported by all TeX compilers):

```
pdflatex "&theclass" test
```

Or option `--fmt` (supported by TeX Live):

```
pdflatex --fmt=theclass test
```

Also `pdftex` could be used, but it uses the wrong search paths for plain format instead of LaTeX. This can be fixed by overwriting the program name:

```
pdftex --progname=pdflatex --fmt=theclass test
```

### Installation

The format file can be found in the current directory or installed in a `texmf` (TDS) tree. The format file `theclass.fmt` for engine pdfTeX is installed in:

```
TDS:web2c/pdftex/theclass.fmt
```

The root can be the home tree (`TEXMFHOME`) or a local tree (`TEXMFLOCAL`).
The latter (or MiKTeX) requires the update of the file name database. The programs `texhash` or `mktexlsr` can be used in TeX Live for this purpose.

Comment: I hope you get many upvotes for your effort.

Comment: As an answer to the question, @Johannes_B is surely right. But I worry that the question asked is not the right one. In that sense.... That is, I entirely agreed with your comment on the question but that is not, as it were, reflected at all in the answer....