# C style compilation of tex document

Tags: compiling, modules

Would it be possible to implement a C style compilation model for tex documents? That is

```
latex -S file_1.tex file_2.tex file_3.tex #produce some kind of object files with "Undefined references"
latexlink -o repor.dvi file_1.txo file_2.txo file_3.txo #Link the chapters (put the data in that order)
```

This would have the benefit of creating scope for preambles so providing a MWE would be much easier. The idea is that the "object files" will not contain any macros that can infer with other stuff, and these "txo" files can be reused in other documents as well. Also it would improve compilation speed, since not the entire document needs to be recompiled.

Comment: This is already there.  It is called a format.

Comment: @HenriMenke Not really. Formats do much less than what the stage to "Undefined references" is.

Comment: @yo' I can't think of a mechanism (that would actually work) to save already output pages in such a manner that they can be easily stacked together to a full document.  Everything else, i.e. macros which can be reused across documents and do not depend on the document itself, can be realised with a format.

Comment: @HenriMenke But what if the macros depend on the way how the document is typeset? This can happen and does happen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that this is not possible, for a very simple reason: resolving the label changes the line breaking and page breaking, which can change the labels. The problem is that -- in some sense -- TeX is too powerful: Even the slightest change in the document can change the way how the whole rest of the document is processed by the program, and that's not only on the "where will the stuff go" layer, but also "how will my macros be defined" layer.

As an example, consider that you can have different section headers on even and odd page. This basically means that you have two internal macros -- `\sectionodd` and `\sectioneven` -- for the section, and you call the correct one depending on the parity of the page number. First, this itself is a two-compilation thing: you have to remember the page number from the previous compilation to get it right. Second, the user can define `\sectionodd` and `\sectioneven` in a very strange way, he can decide that one of them will change the basic macros of the engine etc. and since you can't predict this, you can't know for sure what's going on until you trully process the document with everything that should be there.

Needless to say, as noted above, custom formats do exist and they can be formed moreorless of what you put in the preamble. More details are for instance in [Own cls to fmt conversion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253409/11002).

Comment: In my opinion it's the `box` mechanism. What's inside a box can't be opened again ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer hmmmm `\unhbox` .....

Comment: @yo' I changed from "pages" to data. Sure, the linker may need to run twice. But the point is that there must be no macros that change their definition between runs. So the problem is probably not things like pages, but rather bibliography style macros. Ignoring that, would TeX be a suitable format for the lowlevel output for a modular compilation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I meant: The information is in the box and can't be accessed again until `\unhbox`ed and then it's in page box list -- I wasn't precise enough!

Comment: @user877329 I think you do not understand it. I can do things like `\ifnum\value{page}=146\relax \let\hbox\vbox\fi`. If this code appears on page `146`, it changes the definition of the macro `\hbox` to `\vbox`, which almost surely breaks LaTeX. If the code is elsewhere, nothing happens. Of course, this example is useless, but there are cases where you do things like this. To mention one: output routine changes, as performed e.g. by `longtable`.

Comment: @yo' I guess by “oddity” you meant parity.  Also the section thing is a really weird example.  Why didn't you just choose something like typesetting the page number in the outside margin?  In other words: +1

Comment: @yo' It should be possible to leave everything that relates to pages to the linker. This is actually what happens in C as well.

Comment: @user877329 But that means leaving ***everything*** to the linker, because based on the page breaking, you can redefine everything. In C, this is impossible, once you have a function called `bla`, it's `bla`. In TeX, even the meaning of the language's primitives can be changed (and it is commonly changed, LaTeX changes a good handful of them). You can't even do what Python allows, that is, to pre-parse the program, because the meaning of ``\\`` and `{` etc. can be changed (and is commonly changed, e.g. in `\verb`), therefore the parser cannot be fixed to one syntax.